# In gVim 9.1 how to have different backgrounds for text and the empty area to the right of <EOL>, with hlsearch ans syntax highlight still working?

Tags: syntax-highlighting, search, gvim, background

I would like to use two different backgrounds colors `bg1` and `bg2` with:

1. `bg1` for all text on a line (possibly nothing if line is empty) up to the end-of-line,
2. `bg2` for the empty area after the end-of-line,
3. while keeping `hlsearch` working,
4. **and syntax highlighting working**.

For example, if displaying `<empty_area>` as `_`'s starting with `#` on a 16-character-wide window, with `"text"` as the search pattern and a syntax recongizing `if`, it would look like:

```sh
    if "text"#______
    #_______________
        indented#___
```

with:

- anything but the trailing `_`'s with a different background (here black foreground)...
- ...than the trailing `_`'s (here gray foreground),
- except for `"text"` which should be highlighted as the `Search` group (here green foreground),
- and `if` which has the syntax highlighting of the chosen language (here blue foreground).

I have tried this in my `vimrc`:

```
hi Normal     guibg=Gray75
hi Contents   guibg=LightGray
match Contents /.\+.\@!/.
```

but then I lose the pattern match highlighting for `hlsearch`, which is I guess superseded by the `Contents` match.

Is there a proper way to achieve what I want: different backgrounds for text and empty area after EOL, with `hlsearch` **and syntax highlighting** still working ?

PS: The `NonText` group is not relevant, since it links to the empty area *after the buffer*, and not **after each line**.

Comment: The usual (and UI-agnostic) way to visualize whitespace would be `:set list`. While it may not look quite as good, it was built exactly for this use case.

Comment: Indeed, the list option can show an EOL marker that might suffice. Would that work gilgron?

Comment: Adding a character at `EOL` does not fit to my eye, but allowed me to find my solution. Thanks @d-ben-noble and @friedrich.

Comment: I guess the `lcs` (`listchars`) variable was not judiciously set on the file I tried `:set list` with. In fact, with `set lcs=tab:> ,trail:-,extends:>,precedes:<,nbsp:+`, I get a nice complement to the `2match` solution... Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

I would do:

```
highlight SpecialKey guibg=LightGray

highlight Conditional guibg=LightGray
highlight Content guibg=LightGray
highlight Exception guibg=LightGray
highlight Function guibg=LightGray
highlight Include guibg=LightGray
highlight Operator guibg=LightGray
highlight Repeat guibg=LightGray
highlight Statement guibg=LightGray
highlight Structure guibg=LightGray
highlight Type guibg=LightGray

highlight Content guibg=LightGray
autocmd FileType * syntax match Content /\S\+/
```

Comment: This prevents any syntax highlighting, which is an unwanted effect. I have modified the question to include this requirement.

Comment: I have proposed another solution that is working fine at least with Python syntax at my end.

Answer (score 0):

I tried adding those lines to my `.gvimrc` file:

```
    hi Normal     guibg=Gray75
    hi Contents   guibg=LightGray
    match Contents /.\+.\@!/.
    noremap * *N:2mat Search /<C-R>//<C-M>n
```

which solves the `hlsearch`issue.
But the highlighting involving background, like with diffvim, gets broken.
So I fell back on this lighter solution:

```
    hi Normal       guibg=Snow2 guifg=NONE
    hi Contents     guibg=Snow1 guifg=NONE
    2match Contents /$/
```

which highlights the first non-character at `eol`s and is finally noticeable enough.